# Asynctask that is set with alarmmanager fails when the application is closed on android

Tags: android, android-asynctask, alarmmanager

I have a very well working `ASyncTask` when my application is open but you know when you hold that home button on the phone and close applications by sliding them? it crashes.

my `AlarmReceiver` class

```
 public class Alarm-Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
    final Context errorContext = context;
    final UP refUP = new UP(); //just an activity for my toast

    class NotifRequest extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String[]> {
        String NotifUrlStr = String.format(errorContext.getString(R.string.notification_url), Main.Text);

        @Override
        protected String[] doInBackground(String... params) {
            String[] On = new String[2];
            String onProd = "";
            String sonOnTar = "";


            try {
                JSONTokener onTokener = new JSONTokener(Sources.httpConnGet(NotifUrlStr).toString());
                JSONArray onArray=new JSONArray(onTokener);


                JSONObject json_obj_on = onArray.getJSONObject(0);

                onProd = json_obj_on.getString("on");
                if(onProd .equals("0") == false) {
                sonOnTar = json_obj_on.getString("sonon");
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {

                refUP.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                      public void run() {
                          Toast.makeText(errorContext, "Error!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                      }
                    });
                CancelAlarm(errorContext);
            }

            On[0] = onProd;
            On[1] = sonOnTar;
            return On;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String[] onRes) {

            String onSay = onRes[0];
            String onTar = onRes[1];

            if (onSay.equals("0") && onSay != null) {
                NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                        new NotificationCompat.Builder(errorContext)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.akilli_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("New")
                .setContentText("new");

                Intent resultIntent = new Intent(errorContext, UPSiparisler.class);

                        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
                                PendingIntent.getActivity(
                                        errorContext,
                                        0,
                                        resultIntent,
                                        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
                                        );

                        mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);


                        int mNotificationId = 001;

                        NotificationManager mNotifyMgr = 
                                (NotificationManager) errorContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

                        mNotifyMgr.notify(mNotificationId, mBuilder.build());

            }

            super.onPostExecute(onRes);
        }

    }


    NotifRequest notReq = new NotifRequest();
    notReq.execute();

}

public void SetAlarm(Context context)
{
    AlarmManager am=(AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent i = new Intent(context, AlarmNotifReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i, 0);
    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 10*1000, pi); // Millisec * Second
}

public void CancelAlarm(Context context)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmNotifReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.cancel(sender);
}


 }
```

What should I do for this to work even after the application is closed and not keep showing the `Toast` "error"

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your activity you should try cancelling also your `AsyncTask` when the Activity moves to stopped state, like this:

```
  @Override
  public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        notReq.cancel(true); 
  }
```

I assume when the activity is not visible then you don't need your AsyncTask to finish.

Comment: I do, as I've said I want it to work even when the app. is closed. It does though I've just found out that I can't simply define the string like this. 
String NotifUrlStr = String.format(errorContext.getString(R.string.notification_url), Main.Text);

do you have any suggestions for this?

Comment: well my problem is about using getString() method in an inapplicable class, how can I use it?

Comment: try `errorContext.getResources().getString(R.string.notification_url)`

Comment: I did try it but also I need to add , Main.Text at the and so that I can alter the string, how can I hold the Main.Text string in such a class?

Comment: Main.Text is initialized where?

Comment: in my Main activity, I can use this in my receiver class when the application is open but when I close it, since the Main activity finishes too it can't see the text.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48134/discussion-between-donfuxx-and-suhrahj-rothgar)

Comment: Can you put your text as an extra to your pending Intent?

Comment: @JackTools.Net I could not, probably 'I' could not, but as a work around I initialized another String in my Receiver class and used SharedPreferences and just saved that new String which receives the Main string in the beginning

Comment: Use i.putExtra("MainText", main.text); in your setAlarm method to give some values to your intent.